# Команды a2ensite и a2dissite в apache2

Tags: apache

Часто натыкаюсь на комнады `a2ensite` и `a2dissite` на различных сайтах, но в официальной документации их ни разу не видел, в связи с этим возникает несколько вопросов:

1. Откуда произошли команды `a2ensite` и `a2dissite`?
2. Почему их нет в документации **Apache2**?
3. Есть ли другие схожие вспомогательный комнады и где можно найть их полный список?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Это команды-помощники из пакета `apache2-common` для ОС на основе `Debian`.
2. Их нет в документации к `Apache2`, т.к. они реализованы на уровне отдельного пакета для дистрибутивов на основе `Debian`.
3. Можно посмотреть [в мануале на Debian.org](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apache2/index.html)

Приведу список:

- `a2ensite`, `a2dissite` - активировать или деактивировать сайт/виртуальный хост
- `a2enconf`, `a2disconf` - активировать или деактивировать файл конфигурации
- `a2enmod`, `a2dismod` - активировать или деактивировать модуль
- `a2query` - возвращает различную информацию из текущей конфигурации `Apache2`

Аргументы и более подробное описание в мануале из пункта 3, либо по команде `man %command%`, например `man a2ensite`.